# How do I run a unit test in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit

I am using Android Studio 1.5 with Gradle 1.5 on a Mac (El Capitan). I am following the tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html. But the tutorial does not match the facts.

**Some Discrepancies:**

- When I look at my project structure through the mac Finder, the `src` folder has 3 folders: `androidTest, main, test`. But the tutorial says I should see 2, `main, test`.
- Now in Android Studio, in `Android` perspective, under `app >> java` I see 2 packages: `com.company.myapp` which corresponds to folder `main` and `com.company.myapp(androidTest)` which corresponds to folder `androidTest`. So there I cannot find the `test` folder.
- If I proceed to create my Test class under `androidTest`, then when I run my test I get exception `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.company.myapp.MyTest`
- if I switch from `Android` to `Project` perspective, then I can finally find the `test` folder. But putting things in the `test` folder is a dead-end. First there is a red circle on the file name. Still when I right click to run it, I get the error `Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.RuntimeException’` `Empty test suite`

Here is my test

```
@Test
public void basicTest(){
    System.out.println("Is this running?");
    int a = 5;
    int b = 8;
    assertThat(a, equalTo(b));
}
```

Comment: Have you set the Build Variants target to 'Unit Tests'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the view you are in (*Project* or *Android*) you will either see all directories, or just the current active folders (source directories).

`androidTest` is used for Instrumentation tests.

As you are trying to do, `test` is the correct location to place your files.

To switch between Unit and Instrumentation tests in the Android view you need to select `Build Variants -> Test Artifact` on the left of your IDE. Here you can select the kind of tests you want to run.

The code within the non-active directory will not be indexed, so this is why you see those errors on these files. Switching the Test Artifact will solve this issue.

Also, keep in mind that you can always run your unit tests with gradle by just issuing the

```
gradlew test
```

command.

Happy Testing!